# Are (quasi-)regular polytopes uniquely determined by their edge graph?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes

I consider polytopes $P\subset\Bbb R^n,n\ge 2$ of arbitrary dimension (intersection of finitely many halfspaces, therefore convex), which are vertex- and edge-transitive (also called [*quasi-regular*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiregular_polyhedron)).

> **Question**: Can there exist two different such polytopes $P_1\subset \Bbb R^{n_1}$ and $P_2\subset\Bbb R^{n_2}$, maybe even of different dimensions, which have isomorphic edge-graphs (1-skeletons)? If one polytope is just the other one but embedded in a higher dimension, I consider these to be the same.

What if I drop edge-transitivity and instead use some suitable higher-dimensional generalization of [*uniform polyhedrons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polyhedron), or even weaker, require only that the edges are of the same length.

---

**Update**

I found two statements, relevant for this question:

- [*Simple polytopes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polytope#cite_note-k-4) are uniquely determined by their edge-graphs. However, the definition of "simple polytope" fixes the dimension, so there might be higher dimensional realizations too.
- [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/9268/108884) on MO (and the comments) explain that for $K_n,n\ge 5$, there is a polytope of dimension $4\le d\le n-1$ which has $K_n$ as an edge-graph (see [*neighborly polytopes*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborly_polytope)). So the dimension is not uniquely determined. However, I do not know which of these realizations of $K_n$ is vertex- and/or edge-transitive.

Comment: @M.Winter: See my note ["Spectral Realizations of Graphs"](http://dlnds.com/mathdocs/Spectral-Realizations-of-Graphs.pdf). The Gallery of Graphs shows "spectral" realizations of the $1$-skeletons of the uniform polyhedra (and others). Each realization is compatible with the isometry group of the standard form; in the uniform cases, this guarantees vertex-transitivity (but not equal edges). Although "most" figures have non-planar faces and whatnot, some are proper polyhedra. See, in particular, any figure identified as having a "pseudo-classical" form. (Consult the table in Figure 4, p.11.)

Comment: @Blue I already came across your notes during my research, and it was very interesting. To be honest, I am asking above question exactly because I am trying to realize edge graphs using the associated Laplace matrix (in contrast to the adjacency matrix, this might have the advantage that I know exactly that I have to look at the eigenvectors to the second-smallest eigenvalue). However, if there are multiple harmonious realizations of a given edge graph, it is not clear which one will be given to me via this method. I want to exclude this ambiguity.

Comment: The spectral realizations of the $1$-skeleton of an edge-transitive graph are necessarily edge-transitive, so we can look through my Gallery for examples. Here's one: The cuboctahedron (p.18) has a faithful realization in $\mathbf{R}^5$ (corresponding to eigenvalue $-2$ of its adjacency matrix). How's that?

Comment: Look up "neighbourly polytope".

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Thanks, but is it known how many of these are convex and quasi-regular?

Comment: @Blue Interesting. But something seems off. By the theorem of Balinski, the 1-skeleton of a $k$-dimensional convex polyhedron must be $k$-connected. However, the cuboctahedron graph is not 5-connected, because it is regular of degree 4.

Comment: @M.Winter: It's possible —perhaps even likely— that the spectral cuboctahedron in $\mathbb{R}^5$ is non-convex or something. Spectral realizations guarantee only to respect the combinatorial structure of the $1$-skeleton (automorphisms become isometries), without regard for geometric properties of convexity, face-planarity, etc. Hmmm ... Maybe something else in the Gallery would work, but I'm not in a position at the moment to do more investigation.

Comment: @Blue I understand and I appreciate your help. I want to emphasize that the properties convexity, vertex-transitivity and edge-transitivity are *very* important for *both* realizations. I will check out your gallery again too.

Answer (score 1):

(Quasi-)regular polytopes surely are not uniquely defined by their edge graphs. Just consider the icosahedron x3o5o and the great dodecahedron x5o5/2o. In fact the latter is an edge-faceting of the former (i.e. respecting the same edge graph).

But as soon as you add the (true) convexity constraint, you enforce the edges to be exposed. Thus, again by the very convexity constraint, the only convex figure with that edge skeletton will be the hull polytope thereof.

Neither regularity, uniformity, orbiformity plays any role here nor does transitivity of edges (like quasiregular ones), regularity of faces (like CRF polytopes), or whatever. It is just (true) convexity which ensures that all edges have to be exposed. And that is what is relevant to this argument.

--- rk

Comment: Thank you! So do we know whether every 1-skeleton realizes a *unique* (truly) convex polytope? Maybe I use an uncommon definition of polytope compared to what they mean combinatorically. My polytopes are intersections of half-spaces, so the great dodecahedron is excluded.

Comment: As soon as you exclude halfspaces that are based on corealmic hyperplanes, then all edges will be exposed. Convexity in a lesser sense already would emanate from your definition, but this exposure of all edges then just is what makes the edge skeletton of the hull not only being a subset, but rather the full set of edges.

Comment: What I'm addressing here is when you would dissect a square of a cube by a diagonal. Then the 2 face planes of those triangles are coplanar. And that diagonal edge, even so being a well-defined edge of your polytope, will not be obtained from the edge set of the mere hull (which is the usual cube without any dissections). In that case the edge set is not being obtained back. It rather is the additional requirement that the internal dihedral angles at those edges is less than 180 degrees, which makes the edges being (truely) exposed. This is, what I was addressing with true convexity.

Answer (score 0):

During my research, I found out that *only* vertex-transitivity and convexity is *not* enough to ensure that the 1-skeleton is uniquely realizable. So the remaining question is whether edge-transitivity, uniformity or a requirement on the edge lengths can make it unique.

The counter-example I found was among the [*cyclic polytopes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_polytope), which are a specific way to construct *neighborly polytopes* in higher dimensions. E.g. the $K_n,n\ge 5$ can be realized as a simplex in $n-1$ dimensions, or as a cyclic polytope in a lower dimension.

The crucial detail I now came across was that cyclic polytopes in *even* dimensions are combinatorially vertex-transitive *and* can be realized in the same dimension in a way that realizes all the automorphisms of their face-lattice (see [this paper](http://www.math.uni-magdeburg.de/~kaibel/ALT/Downloads/cyclaut.pdf)). This means: besides the simplices, there are indeed vertex-transitive (convex) polytopes with $K_n$ as their 1-skeleton. However, I found nothing about whether they can be realized edge-transitive or with any other symmetry.

---

**Update**

I just realized, that the only way to place $n$ points equidistant, we need to arrange them as the vertices of the $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex.  Therefore, the only realization of $K_n$ as an edge-transitive polytope (or even as a polytope with equal edge lengths) is the simplex.

Hence, a possible counter-example cannot be neighborly.